# How to get the index of the element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The NodeList don't have a indexOf(element) method? So, how can I get the element index?

Comment: can you un-accept the accepted answer please? The person who wrote it even agrees it's not the best answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By iterating over the elements, and checking if it matches.

Generic code that finds the index of the element within it's parents `childNodes` collection.

```
function index(el) {
    var children = el.parentNode.childNodes,
        i = 0;
    for (; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] == el) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Usage:

```
// should return 4
var idx = index(document.body.childNodes[4]);
```

EDIT: I can't delete an accepted answer, but @kennebec's answer below is much better, which I'll quote verbatim:

> You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf.call()` like this
>
> ```
> let nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
> Array.prototype.indexOf.call(nodes, document.body);
> ```

Comment: is there a design reason the nodelist doesn't have an indexof operation?

Comment: use Array.prototype.indexOf.call(NodeList, element)

Comment: I wish I could upvote your username other than the answer @try-catch-finally

Answer (score 76):

You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf.call()` like this

```
let nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(nodes, document.body);
```

Comment: To make it mega obvious, usage is like `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(haystack, needle);`

Comment: definitely works, but I like the ES6 approach below better since it does not rely on future compatibility guess. My guess is that calling built-in functions on random stuff is more likely to get deprecated than Array.from(NodeList)...

Answer (score 31):

The NodeList object is an Array-like object. So it's possible to "convert" it into an Array using [`Array.prototype.slice.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects)

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(yourNodeListObject); // Now it's an Array.
arr.indexOf(element); // The index of your element :)
```

On browsers that support ES6 you can also do this with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
const arr = Array.from(yourNodeListObject);
```

or using the [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const arr = [...yourNodeListObject];
```

Comment: You can use it like this:
`var listOfElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.parentElement.children), // Now it's an Array.
indexInList = listOfElements.indexOf(node);`

Answer (score 3):

Just add one line in your script:

```
NodeList.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;   // for IE11
```

Then use *indexOf* as usual:

```
var index = NodeList.indexOf(NodeElement);
```

Comment: it seems to work, OK. But why ? could you explain ?

Comment: More explanation would be nice. But on face value it seems to be just a roundabout way of casting into an array which is why it works the same way as the answers above.

Comment: @Chrysotribax It works because:
1. First line just copies reference to `indexOf` method of `Array` into `NodeList` prototype.
2. Since `indexOf` method _reference_ already in NodeList prototype you can invoke it from `NodeList` instance.
Internal implementation of `indexOf` works well with _pseudo-arrays_.
Anyway, it isn't the best solution. Better solutions you can find above.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have the following line:

```
const list=document.querySelectAll('.some_class .someother_class');
```

list will be a nodelist.
So we can convert the nodelist to an array and create a new array of indexes as follows:

```
const indexArr= [...list].map( element => return [...list].indexOf(element) );
```

indexArr contains all the indexes of elements in the original list.