# Array.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

In my html code I have 20 input (`<input type='text'>`)elements. I want to get the index of the element I focused; Hence, before the end of `<body>`, in `<script>`, I wrote:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
function getIndex(el){
    console.log(inputs.indexOf(el));
}
```

and added the following in every input element in html:

```
<input type='text' onfocus='getIndex(this)'>
```

but the console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: inputs.indexOf is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845) - your `inputs` is not an array.

Comment: Why do you even need the index of the element? You have direct access to the element via `this`, so finding its index seems superfluous.

Comment: I would get the index of the input element and there is a `<div>` associated with every input whose property I want to change say : `document.querySelectorAll('.parentDiv div')[index].style.color='blue';`

Comment: And you expect those indexes to match? Seems better to have a more robust system where you nest the tags. Then you can just traverse the DOM to find them, instead of having to look them up by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name

You can make the collection into array using either `Array.from()` or [`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
function getIndex(el){
    console.log([...inputs].indexOf(el));
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onfocus='getIndex(this)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780111/getting-index-of-element-clicked-with-array-prototype-indexof-call) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779986/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-element-in-javascript), you can use Array.prototype.indexOf.call to apply the Array indexOf() function on the NodeList.

```js
const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
function getIndex(el) {
  console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(inputs, el));
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onfocus='getIndex(this)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question!
This is a little tricky!

This happens because `.indexOf` runs on an Array and `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is not an array.

You can simple convert it into an array and then use it:
`var arr = [...htmlCollection];` or `var arr = [].slice.call(htmlCollection);`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) for more details!